# Can a person be able to objectively identify when and how their thinking process is being affected by cognitive biases?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, bias, metacognition

or years, I've always thought I can do a pretty good job of identifying when I have committed a bias, fallacy or some other heuristic.   I'm not saying I avoid them, but at least can admit to myself I did it.  If I'm researching a point online to back up an argument, I know I'm committing Confirmation bias when I'm only looking for articles that support my point of view.   Or, if I'm driving and I'm stuck behind a car that's driving too slow, I immediately think "asshole" even while knowing I'm committing the Fundamental attribution error.

However,  I'm also aware of the Bias blind spot and the Introspection illusion  and know that I may not be nearly as capable of self-identifying heuristical errors as I believe I am.  Part of my identity is as a person who can be honest with himself when deciding how my behaviors and decisions were flawed due biases, fallacies, etc.  I'd love to find out for sure how much of that is just an illusion.

I'm especially interested in research in Metacognition, introspection, and how it relates to the bias blind spot and introspection illusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does fixing cognitive biases do more harm than use?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/does-fixing-cognitive-biases-do-more-harm-than-use)